# Is there a word in German that equal to the region in country/region?

Tags: single-word-request

[Die Regierung der Volksrepublik China jedoch betrachtet Taiwan als eine „abtrünnige Provinz“](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republik_China_(Taiwan)#cite_ref-41)
PROC(normally called as China) think Taiwan is a "split province(similar to 16 Ländern in Deutschland)". Once ROC(normally called as Taiwan) did exist a Taiwan province, but now the concept of the province is gradually eliminated, and most of the time Taiwan refers to the ROC.
Due to the strength of China, almost all companies in English-speaking countries use country/region.

When the choice menu is the country, it means that Taiwan has become a country.
Is there a  word in German that is equal to the region in country/region?

Comment: Maybe _Bundesland_ or more probably _**Landkreis**_. I am not familiar with the hierarchical organization of Taiwan though. Also that would only apply for Germany, Swiss wich is also partially a German speaking country, has a completely different hierarchy of _"regions"_. In Austria it's more or less the same organizational region hierarchy as Germany IIRC.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I modified the question to explain the current situation in Taiwan and China. In addition, I found that the translation of "Ländern" in Chinese is the same as country.

Comment: _Region_ and _Provinz_ are also usual german words. The problem is they probably won't fit for the concrete organizational structure. It depends on the context where you want to use these. Is it a software form select combobox, or a translation of natural speech?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's a software form select combo box.  i.e On the Apple webpage:Choose your country or(/) region.

Comment: Well that was what I am afraid of: These kind  forms are usually inherently bad  to distinguish countries (nations), counties (federal states) and regions (provinces). From international agreement (except China) Taiwan should count as its own country, and not as a region or province.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In German, it should be "Region" as well, so you would have "Land/Region".

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem at all in German as we have the wonderful ambiguous term **Land**, which covers all sorts of political and/or geographical entities.

For example, in everyday German

> Das Braunschweiger Land ist eine Region.
>
> Das Land Hadeln ist eine historische Landschaft.
>
> Deutschland ist ein Land.
>
> Berlin ist innerhalb Deutschlands ein Land.
>
> Schottland ist ein Land innerhalb Großbritanniens.
>
> Die U.S.A. sind ein Land.
>
> Australien ist ein Land und ein Kontinent.
>
> Taiwan ist ein Land.

We really don't care.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these terms would fit well for a selection combo-box in a UI form of a software :-(.

Comment: Label the combo box as **Land**. Put *Taiwan* into it as a selectable option. This may mean anything, from province to country. German doesn't care. You are done.

Comment: Some regtions are called *Land*, but regtions like the Kraichgau or the Eifel are rarely called *Land*.

Comment: @Janka: I don't think that's a good solution. Yes, the term "Land" can be interpreted in quite different ways in German, but without any further qualification, an input field labeled "Land" implies the political entity of a souvereign national country - not of any smaller administrative subdivision that also happens to be called "Land", with or without some prefix, nor of a random region that happens to be called "Land", nor of anything else with "Land" in its name, such as "Legoland" or "Kaufland". Least of all, I would expect such an input field/dropdown list to offer an arbitrary ...

Comment: I think it's a very good solution because that ambiguity is exactly what the questioner needs.

Comment: ... mixture of national states and administrative subdivisions (all of them, everywhere in the world? Or just some whose souvereignity is disputed? Or just those that happen to be called "Land" for some reason?).

Comment: Correct. The questioner most likely wants to fill that list with names of **postal entities** (or something like this), neither with geographical nor political ones.

Comment: @Janka: My point is that there is no such ambiguity. By writing "Land: Taiwan", you are making a clear statement that you consider Taiwan a souvereign country, not a  province of the PRC. That's precisely what the questioner wants to avoid, and what *can* be avoided by writing "Land/Region" or something like that.

Comment: Region is *America, EMEA, East Asia, Africa, Ozeania* in world maps.

Comment: And no, as I wrote in my answer, *Land* does not imply sovereignity.

Comment: @Janka: I disagree. When a German native speaker asks me "Aus welchem Land kommst du?", I would not even remotely think of the possibility that they are inquiring about my *Bundesland* or even just a random place that happens to be called "Land" rather than asking whether I'm from Germany. I concede that you may see this differently, but the fact that this solution would be misleading even for some native speakers indicates it should be treated with caution.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you seem to be missing the problem that you might get two different answers from a state-official or a native, when asking which *Land* a Taiwanese comes from. China is a country, Taiwan is a Country, and many things more, only the CPR is a Republic in official terms and the Province of Taiwan is a state. Yet, *Staat* might imply a statement. Nevertheless the choice of words doesn't matter, if inclusion in the list is a statement already. Thus any uncharged term would become potentially charged virtually by the sole merit of inclusion in the list.

Comment: @vectory: Not at all, that is precisely the problem that labeling such a field "Country/Region" rather than just "Country" is supposed to mitigate. It allows all involved parties to "save face" by not making a definitive statement whether e.g. Taiwan is a (souvereign) country or just a region within China that is (e.g. for matters of postal processing) treated separately for one reason or another. That is also why mere inclusion in that list is not a statement on its own.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper of course inclusion is a statement unless you include Shenzen, Xianjang and other provinces, too, next to CPR, which would be redundant.

Comment: @vectory: Well, is e.g. mail to the city of Shenzhen or the province of Xinjiang handled any differently than to the rest of mainland China? Probably not. Is mail to Taiwan handled any differently? Presumably it is, given that Taiwan uses a different system of postal codes than PRC, and that mail between PRC and Taiwan is, as far as I could find out, treated as international rather than domestic mail. That alone warrants inclusion of Taiwan as a separate item in a list that deals e.g. with postal addresses.